# HTTP Fetch Spotify API token request failure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, spotify

Under guidance of the Spotify WebAPI doc I am trying to request an access token via Client Credentials method. [Spotify API Doc](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/). I want to use a regular HTTP fetch request, I can not use any 3rd party libraries. I am getting a 400 return status error response:

> {error: "unsupported_grant_type", error_description: "grant_type parameter is missing"}.

However, I believe my request should be formatted correctly for its grant type. I have looked at tons of articles, MDN doc, and the Spotify doc and I can not figure out why this is not working. I will include the code which I have obviously taken the API keys out of but they are correct. [Link to code](https://pastebin.com/M3s3rBw2).

```
//Basic imports
import React, { Component, useState , useEffect } from 'react';
//Custom IMPORTS: 
import '../PageCss/HeaderSection.css'



const Spotify = () => {


    const [baseUrl, setBaseUrl] = useState("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
    const [token, setToken] = useState([]);
    const [currentStatus, setStatus] = useState(false);

    const client_id = '';
    const client_secret = '';
    const data = { grant_type: 'client_credentials' };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(baseUrl,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')
                },
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error("Response Error!"));
        }
        else {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .then((json) => {
        try {
          setToken(json.results);
          setStatus(true);
          console.log("TOKEN:" + token)

        }
        catch
        {
          return Promise.reject(new Error(`State Error!: Data: ${token} , Connection:${currentStatus}`));
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }, [baseUrl]);


    return (

        <div >
             
        </div>
    )
};



export default Spotify;
```

[image]
[image]

My application is a react app, hosted on GitHub. It's a fully functioning site and everything else is working fine. My other API fetch calls are working fine so I know this one must have an issue in it. The only line of code giving me an error is this 400 status from the fetch request.

Comment: Side note: the example that Spotify's Doc gives seems to be outdated, as the library they use to make the request is deprecated.

Comment: `Content-Type` header should not be `application/json`? ...maybe they forgot to update the docs :))

Comment: Yeah idk the doc seems really weird haha

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I actually got the inital token request to work with this code:

```
fetch(baseUrl,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + client_id + '&client_secret=' + client_secret,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
```

Inspired by the OAuth doc and some more researching. It works now and I have a token from Spotify.